# Delete all text in a file between two strings without importing any modules

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, text-processing

Due to restrictions I can't use any import modules like `re`, `sys` or `os` etc. 
Anything that I have to import at the beginning is out. This has made my life hell.
Here is what I've got so far:

```
#I CANT USE ANY IMPORT MODULES DUE TO RESTRICTIONS ON THE MACHINE THIS RUNS ON :(
#
# These Are the Variables for our file path and the start and ending points of what I want to delete.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DelStart = "//StartBB"
DelEnd = "//EndBB"
FilePath = "C:\\Users\\kenne_000\\Desktop\\New folder\\test.sqf"
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Opens the FilePath in Read set this command to f
f = open(FilePath).read()


#Sets value of out to create file in Write mode called "Filepath".out
Out = open(FilePath + '.out', 'w')


#assigns fL as open FilePath and split it up line by line for indexing
fL = f.split('/n')


#Assings LN as index our file and find the lines DelStart and DelEnd
LN = fL.index(DelStart,DelEnd)

#This Gives an error 
#>>> LN = fL.index(DelStart,DelEnd)
#Traceback (most recent call last):
# File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method


#text is replacing everything between our start and endpoints with nothing ""
# STILL NEED THIS SECTION NO CLUE HOW TO DO THIS


#Writes our new file Minus our designated start and end points
out.write(text)


#Closes Our New File
out.close()


#Ends Script
Script.close()
```

I was able to create a script that wrote all of the text and inserted the markers, which are individual for each set of text that gets inserted, but I no longer have any clue what to do when it comes to removing the section between the markers.

Comment: `fL` is a list of lines. and `fL.index` will fine a *line* not part of it.

Do you need to delete for every line or for the whole file? In any case, use *string* index to find start and end then slice away. Something like:

    i = line.find(DelStart)
    j = line.find(DelEnd)
    print line[:i] + line[j+len(DelEnd):]

Comment: Is there any chance you can show me  this in a code snippet?

Comment: also The entire Line is //StartBB  then the next line the text starts and then at the end on its own line is //EndBB   NM i get what you mean now XD

Comment: The last part is code example, for some reason didn't format properly.

Comment: yeah you have to do it as an answer code dosnt format in comments

Comment: Also the goal is to remove //StartBB + //EndBB and all the text inbetween

Comment: Lazy Thanks so much your answer worked, if you could please post your first comment as an answer so i can give you credit and award you the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the code in your self-answer looks like it ought to work, it's not particularly elegant:

1. You should really be using a `with` block to work with files.
2. Your variable `line` is misnamed: it doesn't contain a line at all, but the entire contents of your input file.
3. Your script reads in the entire file at once, which may be problematic for large files in terms of memory use.

Here's an alternative:

```
def excise(filename, start, end):
    with open(filename) as infile, open(filename + ".out", "w") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.strip() == start:
                break
            outfile.write(line)
        for line in infile:
            if line.strip() == end:
                break
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line)
```

This function uses [`with open(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) (scroll down to the paragraph starting "It is good practice to use the with keyword ...") to ensure that files will be properly closed even if you hit an error of some kind, as well as reading and writing one line at a time to conserve memory.

If you have a file **example.txt** with the following content:

```
one
two
three
//StartBB
four
five
six
//EndBB
seven
eight
nine
```

... then calling `excise()` as follows ...

```
excise("example.txt", "//StartBB", "//EndBB")
```

... will do what you want:

**example.txt.out**

```
one
two
three
seven
eight
nine
```

Answer (score 1):

CREDITS FOR THIS ANSWER GOES TO lazy1 and his comment solution:

> fL is a list of lines. and fL.index will fine a line not part of it.
>   Do you need to delete for every line or for the whole file? In any
>   case, use string index to find start and end then slice away.
>   Something like: i = line.find(DelStart) j = line.find(DelEnd) print
>   line[:i] + line[j+len(DelEnd):]

```
# These Are the Variables for our file path and the start and ending points of what I want to delete.
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DelStart = "//StartBB" #Replace This With Proper Start Que
DelEnd = "//EndBB" #Replace this with the proper End Que
FilePath = "FILEPATH GOES HERE"
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Sets Line to open our filepath and read it
line = open(FilePath).read()

#i finds our start place j finds our ending place
i = line.find(DelStart)
j = line.find(DelEnd)


#sets text as finding start and end and deleting them + everything inbetween
text = line[:i] + line[j+len(DelEnd):]

#Creates our out file and writes it with our filter removed
out = open(FilePath + '.out', 'w')
out.write(text)


#Closes Our New File
out.close()


#Ends Script
Script.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses only built-in string functions:

```
    string = "This is the string"
    stringA = "This"
    stringB = " string"
    stringC = stringA + stringB
    stringD = stringC.replace(string, stringC)
```

Comment: The goal however is to delete everything from //StartBB  ALL THIS TEXT ETC SPANNING MULTILE LINES all the way through //EndBB so that when script has finished all of that is gone.

Answer (score 0):

A rewrite of the important part of @KennethDWhite 's answer, as a function. I would simply have posted it as a comment to his answer, but that would not format correctly.

```
# ToDo: this also deletes the delimiters. Perhaps add a parameeter to indicuate 
#       whether to do so,or just to delete the text between them?
def DeleteStringBetween(string, startDelimiter, endDelimiter):
    startPos = string.find(startDelimiter)
    endPos   = string.find(endDelimiter)

    # If either delimiter was not found, return the string unchanged.
    if (startPos == -1) or (endPos == -1):
        return string

    return string[:startPos] + string[endPos + len(endDelimiter):]
```